# WooCommerce change number of columns in the frontpage

Tags: css, plugins

I've been looking for an answer for a couple of days now. I've tried every snippet possible, changing the functions files, creating a separate template for content products but I can't change the number of products listed. Currently WooCommerce displays 4 products per row. Adding a css class of "last" to that fourth product. I want to display the products in a line of three products.

Here is the url to the current store: http://teamhappiness.org/store/

Answer (score 2):

You didn't say what snippets you've actually tried, but according to the docs, you can filter [`loop_shop_columns`](http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/codex/extending/hooks/) like so:

```
function wpa65503_woo_shop_columns( $columns ) {
    return 3;
}
add_filter( 'loop_shop_columns', 'wpa65503_woo_shop_columns' );
```

tested and working for me with Twenty Eleven theme.

**EDIT** - this is the particular line in the default `content-product.php` template file that makes the above filter work. you could just set it directly if you're using a custom template file and don't need it filterable:

```
// Store column count for displaying the grid
if ( empty( $woocommerce_loop['columns'] ) )
    $woocommerce_loop['columns'] = apply_filters( 'loop_shop_columns', 4 );
```

Comment: Just added that code but it still displays 4 columns.

Comment: where did you add it? in your theme's `functions.php`? if it still displays 4 columns then there's something elsewhere in your theme setting number of columns.

Comment: I changed it on the theme's funtions.php and I've created a template file for content-product.php

Comment: Does your template file apply the filter? see edit above.

Comment: Yeah, same thing. There has to be something overwriting it...

Comment: inspect the global `$wp_filter` or do a theme-wide search for the `loop_shop_columns` filter hook.

Answer (score 1):

Hey guys I was searching around the same issue; just found the solution! It's not involving content-product.php at all (at least in my case), it's involving the file woocommerce > single-product > related.php
Make a template of this file (if you don't know how to override WooCommerce template [study that](http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/codex/template-structure/)) and find this code:

```
$args = apply_filters('woocommerce_related_products_args', array(
'post_type'             => 'product',
'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
'no_found_rows'         => 1,
'posts_per_page'        => $posts_per_page,
'orderby'               => $orderby,
'post__in'              => $related
) );
```

All you've got to do is change the variable

```
$posts_per_page
```

In which number of related products you want to display!
For example:

```
'posts_per_page'        => 10,
```

Will display 10 products.

Comment: Be aware that this solution may require you to change the file again after you update WooCommerce.

Comment: No need to copy the template file for this change. See that `woocommerce_related_products_args` filter at the top? That's where you need to hook into to override `posts_per_page`.